# ASP.Net Core Web Site Configuration Issue

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

I have an ASP.Net Core application that I have deployed on multiple hosting services (azure, shared host, etc.).  I am trying to deploy on a new Virtual Server and having trouble getting the web site to start.

I deployed the site using FTP.  It placed the site in the inetpub/vhosts folder.  The site appears to be deployed correctly.  I installed Windows Server Hosting Bundle.

I pointed the IIS to the new directory.  When I access the site, it displays the directory instead of opening the site.  I have researched and tried a few things but can't get it to work.

I also tried to deploy using the WebDeploy method but that fails when I validate my connection saying that the remote computer didn't respond.  That may be a firewall.  I don't know what port it uses.

This is a brand-new virtual server so it is possible that I haven't installed something that is needed.  There was a default website working that was installed by the setup tool.

Tried numerous things found in articles on web.

Comment: Is there a `web.config` file? Or you just deployed the source code?

Comment: There is a web.config file and the processPath points to my app.dll file.

Comment: You will have to share the contents of that file as part of the question, as people often make mistakes inside.

Comment: You said you installed the Windows Server Hosting Bundle, first make sure the ASP.NET Core module is successfully installed in IIS. You can open IIS Manager,
Navigate to your server node, click "Modules" and look for "AspNetCoreModuleV2" in the module list to check if the ASP.NET Core module is installed. This module is responsible for hosting ASP.NET Core applications.

Comment: I was able to get working.  Wrong version of .Net installed.  I set my project to .Net 8 , redeployed, and it worked.

Comment: Then you can post and accept your own answer below, so that future readers can learn from you.